# Cassandra is start but could not connect to localhost

Tags: database, cassandra

I installed the latest version of `Cassandra` and as you see it is running:

> sudo service cassandra status
>
> * Cassandra is running

but when i try `cqlsh` it gives me :

> Connection error: Could not connect to localhost:9160

when i try to connect to the Cassandra of the another server it is work fine

why it is happening and how can i resolve it?

thanks in advance,

---

java -version:"1.7.0_51"

OS:Ubuntu 12.04 lts

Comment: Please show us the output from `netstat -an | grep 9160`.

Comment: Also share any configuration changes you have made.

Comment: thanks @DonBranson , the output is `tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9160          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN` also i have not changed any configuration

Comment: If you `nc localhost 9160` and it hangs, you should be able to connect. If it immediately exits, I'd guess your firewall is configured to block connections to that port.

Comment: Did nc connect or immediately exit?

Comment: when i executed nc 127.0.0.1 9160 it does not show me anything , just prompt is in use

Comment: Yeah, it won't show anything, just connect or fail immediately. I think look at your firewall.

Comment: in your cassandra/conf dir, what do you get with the following command?: `grep listen_address cassandra.yaml`

Comment: thank you @BryceAtNetwork23 , it gives me `listen_address: localhost
# Leaving this blank will set it to the same value as listen_address`

Comment: @MostafaJamareh cassandra log files may help you...